# how to modify the content of a div

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

This is my simple code HTML but it doesn't work with me

```
<html lang="en">
        <head>
            <title>Test</title>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            function getdata() {

                document.getElementById("page").innerHTML="Hello";
            }
        </script>
        </head>
        <body>
         <a id="teachers" href="" name="teachers" onclick="getdata()">Click here </a>
         <div id="page"  name="takak" class="home">
            modify this text 
         </div>
        </body>
</html>
```

I want to modify the content of the div (id="page") when I click on the link . Please can someone help me ?!

Comment: It seems to be working as expected - tried here - http://jsfiddle.net What's wrong?

Comment: @Al.G. Doesnt a blank href reload the current page?

Comment: Maybe... yes, @user3581544 use `href="#"`, not `href=""`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the href destination, for example: "#" (putting # means that it will point to another id or name on the same page, and not to an external URL). It will be:

```
<a id="teachers" href="#" name="teachers" onclick="getdata()">Click here </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {

document.getElementById("teachers").addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World";
});
};

</script>


<a id="teachers" href="" name="teachers">Click here </a>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it's not that what I need, Thanks